# Ajax get does not work on phonegap for external pages

Tags: php, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am using Jquery Mobile 1.4 and phonegap and am having trouble getting ajax to get data from and external link. Here's what I have treid:
including headers in the external page

```
header("Content-type: text/html");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

I've tried setting the following variables:

```
$.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
$.support.cors = true;
```

I've enabled the whitelist:

```
<access origin="*" />
```

Here is my ajax call:

```
$(document).on('pagecreate', '#index', function(){
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://myserver.com/page.php',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'html',
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function(data, status) {
        alert(data);
     }
});
});
```

I've added this to AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Nothing seems to work. I can get ajax to work on internal page and I can also post to external pages. I just cannot get html data from any external page. Can anyone help me? I've been stuck on this for two days now

Answer (score 1):

This is a log shoot but let me guess.

When you're talking about external pages I would guess you're using multi HTML template. I would also assume each page has its own HEAD and BODY content.

If this is the case this is how you can fix it:

jQuery Mobile uses Ajax to load additional pages, but in the process it loads only BODY content, HEAD is discarded. Only initial jQuery Mobile page is fully loaded into the DOM (including HEADE), there's no point in loading it again.

About a solution, several exist, find them **[here](http://www.gajotres.net/how-jquery-mobile-page-handling-affects-javascript-executions/)**.